# checking if all radiogroups in an activity are checked

Tags: java, android, foreach

I have a form in one of my activities, and there are about 10 radiogroups. My problem is that I have to check if one of radiogroups is left without checking?
A sample of my code is shown below:

```
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioq1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/q1f"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:text="@string/conffalse"
            android:textColor="#f05252" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/q1t"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:text="@string/conftrue"
            android:textColor="#37df47" />

     </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: You have 10 radiogroup or buttons?

Comment: you should have to use CheckBox instead of RadioButton/RadioGroup?as your requrement you have to check multiple items.

Comment: @PurpleDroid Yes He has above code 10times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if any button is checked inside a radioGroup with:

```
int checkId =  yourRadioGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

boolean isChecked = false;

if(checkedId==-1){

    isChecked=false;
 }else{

    isChecked=true;
}
```

Do this for every RadioGroup for example with an Array which contains every Radiogroup and a for-loop:

```
RadioGroup[] groups = new RadioGroup{RadioGroup1,RadioGroup2};

for(int i=0;i<groups.length;i++){

 int id = groups[i].getCheckedRadioButtonId();
 if(id==-1){

  isChecked=false;
  break; //break the loop, because if one is not checked, inform the user
 }else{

   isChecked=true;
  }
}
```

The method getCheckedRadioButtonId(); returns -1 if no radioButton is checked.